# ko grid search functionality

Tags: knockout.js, grid

I want to search the data in entire grid but in ko grid the functionality works in different fashion.
We can search only the visible or binded data. And I am slicing the data before binding so that only limited no of records are visible per page.
So an idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You can search on not visible members

In this fiddle I have excluded the name member, you can still search on it

http://jsfiddle.net/A29GA/

```
this.gridOptions = { 
    data: self.myData,
    columnDefs: [{field: 'age', displayName: 'Age'}]
};
```

Comment: That it will work, since all the available data is binded but i have 50 data but i am binding only 10 data. So my search will work only for 10 data. But my requirement is the search to work for 50 data.

Comment: Im not binding name as you can see above only age

Comment: But i am not using ko search function. I am using external filter

Comment: But then its up to you how to filter it, is it not?

Comment: Since i am new to KO so it took time for me to debug this in-depth. In my case i am getting the data from database and binding it to ko grid.Hence the data is not yet available for ko grid, i.e its not available in ur myData. Its still in my json object. So i am slicing it 1st then binding it. This is giving problem for me.:( Hence i am trying it to use the search functionality in a different manner.